# Custom Bot for Microsoft Teams getting "BotAuthenticator failed to authenticate incoming request!" error

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am making a custom bot, using the Bot Framework, for Microsoft teams. I am currently hosting the bot locally and tunneling through ngrok, and I'm using the /api/messages URL. I have registered the bot with the bot framework, and put the bot handle in BotId, app ID in MiscrosoftAppId, and app password in MicrosoftAppPassword in my Web.config. The Teams channel is enabled and has status "Running" on the Bot Framework page. The bot runs on the emulator, and runs on the test connection on the Bot Framework page, but it does not run in Microsoft Teams.

This is what is being sent to my bot:

```
"type": "message",
"id": "1497620296742",
"timestamp": "2017-06-16T13:38:19.303Z",
"localTimestamp": null,
"serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer-client-ss.msg/",
"channelId": "msteams",
"from": {
    "id": "29:1F9b3IgxC3x5ynp7nVxdSQ0bQ9MNyf7uKDZHrrCfRLyBbjOmdWSY4gyFLuR8cTRFmbXOeDN4f_uI65xSem6M5OA",
    "name": "Ronnei, Evan T"
},
"conversation": {
    "isGroup": true,
    "id": "19:d02a9a4678924803964e6af1d9afc1ab@thread.skype;messageid=1497558943513",
    "name": null
},
"recipient": null,
"textFormat": "plain",
"attachmentLayout": null,
"membersAdded": null,
"membersRemoved": null,
"topicName": null,
"historyDisclosed": null,
"locale": null,
"text": "Test Bot",
"summary": null,
"attachments": [
    {
        "contentType": "text/html",
        "contentUrl": null,
        "content": "<div><span itemscope=\"\" itemtype=\"http://schema.skype.com/Mention\" itemid=\"0\">Test Bot</span></div>",
        "name": null,
        "thumbnailUrl": null
    }
],
"entities": [
    {
        "type": "clientInfo",
        "locale": "en-US",
        "country": "US",
        "platform": "Windows"
    }
],
"channelData": {
    "teamsChannelId": "19:d02a9a4678924803964e6af1d9afc1ab@thread.skype",
    "teamsTeamId": "19:e218343840af4d4397faf47bd3f4eada@thread.skype",
    "channel": {
        "id": "19:d02a9a4678924803964e6af1d9afc1ab@thread.skype"
    },
    "team": {
        "id": "19:e218343840af4d4397faf47bd3f4eada@thread.skype"
    },
    "tenant": {
        "id": "a9691d3f-49e3-46a8-8b23-ddad274d0523"
    }
},
"action": null,
"replyToId": null,
"value": null,
"name": null,
"relatesTo": null
```

And it's giving me this 401 Unauthorized error:

```
BotAuthenticator failed to authenticate incoming request!
```

I'm very much a beginner when it comes to all of this stuff. I followed the available tutorials on the Bot Framework documentation, but it still doesn't work on Teams. I'm sort of stuck at this point. Let me know if there's any more information that I should provide.

Apparently I don't have enough reputation to post more code... So here's my manifest.json: https://pastebin.com/xK7y2VHX

Comment: Can you double check if the AppId and AppPassword values are correct?

Comment: They are correct. I even generated a new password and used that just to make sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attached manifest has a few issues:

1. `bots.botsId` needs to be the guid from your botframework's bot
2. both `needsChannelSelector` and `isNotificationOnly` should be bools, not strings (e.g. "needsChannelSelector": false)

(packageName is not a blocking element but should be a unique string ideally in reverse domain name notation, if applicable.)

You can also compare against our simple bot package [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-teams-docs/blob/master/teams/SimpleBotPackage.zip) and make sure you review the [packaging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/createpackage) and [sideloading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/sideload) instructions as well.

Comment: I can successfully access my bot now through the sideloaded package, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That's great you've got your bot working. Have you created a manifest.json file and sideloaded it into Teams? Your manifest contains the appID, botID, and the overall information about your bot. Here are the [packaging instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/createpackage) if not. There's a page below this page that shows the manifest schema. If you've sideloaded it and are still having trouble, please post again!

Comment: My bot isn't working. I'm not sideloading the bot as an app, although I did try that to no avail. I'm using the custom bot feature because I have no plans to publish it as an app as it's purely internal.

Comment: "Custom bot" as it relates to Teams is described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/custombot), which doesn't seem like what you're doing.   When you go through the Bot Framework to register a bot, you're actually creating a proper bot and therefore you need to package and sideload it per the instructions on MSDN.  As you are getting the channel data payload, it sounds as if you have successfully done that, yes?

Comment: Well if I'm going to need to sideload the bot, then I need to fix my manifest.json, because the sideloaded bot doesn't seem to be hitting the actual connection. Here's my manifest.json. I'll edit my main post with it. I wasn't sure if I was doing this correctly. I didn't know what to put in the "packageName" field, and the documentation on the schema wasn't super informative.